# Sonarqube scanner error DirectoryNotEmptyException

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using `sonarqube` scanner on a Citrix remote machine. During the scan, analysis of code completes and gets zipped. But while uploading this zipped file, I get `java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException` and nothing gets uploaded to the `sonarqube` server.

Note that the scanner works fine for small projects. It does not work only for large projects. My `sonarqube` version is 7.2.1. Same thing happened in version 6.7 LTS. But it worked perfectly fine in version 5.6 LTS.

I have tried setting `sonar.ws.timeout=9000` in `sonar-scanner.properties` file to increase time. This did not work.

The error message is:

```
INFO: 7 files had no CPD blocks
INFO: Calculating CPD for 521 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 4886ms, dir size=15 MB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 3769ms, zip size=4 MB
ERROR: Failed to delete temp folder
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\codeAnalyzer\bhatk\.scannerwork\.sonartmp
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProv
ider.java:266)
        at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSyst
emProvider.java:108)
        at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
        at org.sonar.api.utils.internal.DefaultTempFolder$DeleteRecursivelyFileV
isitor.postVisitDirectory(DefaultTempFolder.java:121)
        at org.sonar.api.utils.internal.DefaultTempFolder$DeleteRecursivelyFileV
isitor.postVisitDirectory(DefaultTempFolder.java:110)
        at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2688)
        at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
        at org.sonar.api.utils.internal.DefaultTempFolder.clean(DefaultTempFolde
r.java:97)
        at org.sonar.api.utils.internal.DefaultTempFolder.stop(DefaultTempFolder
.java:106)
        at org.sonar.scanner.analysis.AnalysisTempFolderProvider.stop(AnalysisTe
mpFolderProvider.java:61)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stopAdapters(DefaultPicoContai
ner.java:1048)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.stop(DefaultPicoContainer.java
:803)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.stopComponents(ComponentCo
ntainer.java:165)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer
.java:124)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:
81)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentC
ontainer.java:136)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer
.java:122)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContain
er.java:132)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:71)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.exec
ute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(Iso
latedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner
.java:171)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.j
ava:128)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:111)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE  
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 3:27.575s
INFO: Final Memory: 60M/2882M
INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Fail to request http://localhost:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=my:project
&projectName=My%20project
ERROR: Caused by: timeout
ERROR: Caused by: Socket closed
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging
.
```

Comment: What happens if you stop SonarQube, delete the contents of the .sonartmp folder and restart again?

Comment: Eventually contents of .sonartmp folder gets deleted after the exception is raised. Zipped folder of analysis is the content of .sonartmp.

Comment: Maybe the antivirus is locking the zip file for scanning? I read somewhere that sonar may not work properly if the system has an antivirus

Answer (score 1):

the error caused by default 10s writeTimeout inherited from OkHttp library. While readTimeout is configurable by sonar.ws.timeout param, the writeTimout is not currently configurable. In some cases, depends on the analysis report size and /or your infrastructure setup, 10s is not enough to upload an analysis report that causes socket timeout error and DirectoryNotEmptyException. I have implemented a fix and committed it to SonarSource github: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/pull/3252/files